# How to Asynctask within fragment?

Tags: android

I want to use a DefaultHttpClient/HttpGet asynctask to grab the JSON from the school's site. But I want to request it from within the Fragment.

How can I do that without failing?

This is what I already tried:

```
public class RequestData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    private String Content;
    private Context context;
    private String Error = null;
    private ProgressDialog Dialog;

    public RequestData(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        Dialog.setMessage("Downloading source..");
        Dialog.show();
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            Content = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Error = e.getMessage();
            cancel(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Error = e.getMessage();
            cancel(true);
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        Dialog.dismiss();
        if (Error != null) {
            Toast.makeText(context, Error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Source: " + Content, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Which is called by this:

```
RequestData request = new RequestData(getSherlockActivity());
request.execute(getBaseURL() + "phpinfo.php");
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code? What is the error("failing") you are seeing?

Comment: Whats the error? Post your logs

Comment: Well, actually the Dialog will show up and load forever, so the request will never been done/never end. And the LogCat doesnt show up everything because it isn't really failing...

Comment: Did you try stepping through with a debugger?

Comment: @nasch, what do you mean? I don't really know how to. LogCat/Console don't return anything... Because it actually doesn't go wrong..

Comment: Apparently it has to do with a SSL fail...